# How to customize the file display

Tags: files

I have a problem that I'm unable to solve. I created content type named test player to display files with [Able Player](https://www.drupal.org/project/ableplayer), that is an accessible audio player for blind users. So, I installed requested modules, and it works fine.

Now, when the page gets displayed, there is a link to file, that shows a page with file name and other info. This link is going to be read before the audio player tag from screen reading software. so, if the user click this link, it reaches a page that doesn't have the audio player, but only the name of the file.

I want to display only the audio player without the link to this file. Is there a way? I tried it already with another audio player, but the link appears again.